# date string isn't recognized by "Format" or "Cdate"

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying for hours to convert this string into a date format variable but every try seems not to work,

here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub date()
    Dim m1 As Range
    Dim m As String
    Dim ddate As Date
    Set m1 = Worksheets("dates").Range("A9") 
    'm1 text= "somehting 31-Jan-2019"
    m = Right(m1, 11)
    m = Replace(m, "-", "/") ' "31/Jan/2019
    ddate = CDate(m)

End Sub
```

at the end 'ddate' gets an error of 'types do not match'

Comment: Also of course `Date` is not a valid `Sub` name.

Comment: `cdate("31-Jan-2019")` works fine for me, as does `cdate("31/Jan/2019")`  Suspect your cell value is not what you think it is, or it's related to date locales.

Comment: Try with m = Right(m1.value, 11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some suggestions:**

1. As BigBen said you can not use `Date` as a procedure Name
2. Also, as Tim said, you have to be aware of your regional settings (maybe your system is in English but your month abbreviation is in another language)
3. Always use Option Explicit at the top of your modules (this prevents errors like using a variable that is not declare and misspelling it.
4. Try to name your variables to something you understand later

---

With that said, I solved this using *two approaches*.

Read the comments in each alternative to understand what is happening.

```
Sub ConvertDateAlternative1()

    Dim evalCell As Range
    Dim cellValue As String

    Dim resultYear As Long
    Dim resultMonth As Long
    Dim resultDay As Long

    Dim resultDate As Date

    ' Qualify the full location by adding the workbook. In this case Thisworkbook
    Set evalCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("dates").Range("A9")
    'm1 text= "somehting 31-Jan-2019"

    ' Alternative 1: if you know the exact location of each part of the date

    cellValue = evalCell.Value
    resultYear = Right(cellValue, 4)
    resultMonth = Month(Mid(cellValue, 14, 3) & " 1, 2000") ' -> Build a date from which VBA understands that Jan is month number 1 (this is sensitive to your regional settings)
    resultDay = Mid(cellValue, 11, 2)
    resultDate = DateSerial(resultYear, resultMonth, resultDay)

    Debug.Print "Date alternative 1: is " & Format(resultDate, "dd/mmm/yyyy")

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub ConvertDateAlternative2()

    Dim evalCell As Range
    Dim cellValue As String
    Dim dateParts() As String ' -> In this case we need an array

    Dim resultYear As Long
    Dim resultMonth As Long
    Dim resultDay As Long

    Dim resultDate As Date

    ' Qualify the full location by adding the workbook. In this case Thisworkbook
    Set evalCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("dates").Range("A9")
    'm1 text= "somehting 31-Jan-2019"

    ' Alternative 2: By splitting the last segment of the string (this requires that the date comes after a space in the string)

    ' In a single step combined a split of the string by spaces Split(evalCell.Value, " ") which returns an array
    ' And getting the last item in that array, which would be the date segment
    cellValue = Split(evalCell.Value, " ")(UBound(Split(evalCell.Value, " ")))

    ' Now, split the string that looks like a date by "-"
    dateParts = Split(cellValue, "-")

    ' In this order, day is the first item in the array, then comes the month and then the year
    resultDay = dateParts(0)
    resultMonth = Month(dateParts(1) & " 1, 2000") '-> To this one we apply the same trick as in alternative 1
    resultYear = dateParts(2)

    resultDate = DateSerial(resultYear, resultMonth, resultDay)

    Debug.Print "Date alternative 2: is " & Format(resultDate, "dd/mmm/yyyy")

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: thanks a lot, the problem was in the regional settings so it doesn't recognize the date correct.

Answer (score 0):

`CDate` function is smart enough to figure out the dash-separated date format so there is no need to replace it with the slashes. If you extract the date text and then convert it to a date variable then you can do whatever you want with the date variable. If you want to show it in different format then you have to actually format your cell/range before you paste the value in there. Since you did not provide more samples, I took the liberty and added trim functions to make sure that date texts are extracted correctly:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractDate()
    Dim s As String
    Dim d As Date

    s = Worksheets("dates").Range("A9").Value
    s = RTrim(s) 'remove the trailing space
    s = Right(s, 11)
    s = LTrim(s) 'remove the leading space
    d = CDate(s)

End Sub
```

A better way to do this is by using an array:

```
Sub ExtractDate()
    Dim s As String
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim d As Date

    s = Worksheets("dates").Range("A9").Value
    s = RTrim(s) 'remove the trailing space
    arr = Split(s, " ") 'split by space, so the date segment will be the last element
    s = arr(UBound(arr))
    d = CDate(s)

End Sub
```

and this is a function that can be called from the worksheet too:

```
Function ExtractDate(cell As Range) As Date
    Dim arr As Variant

    arr = Split(RTrim(cell.Value), " ") 'split by space, so the date segment will be the last element
    ExtractDate = CDate(arr(UBound(arr))) 'format cell as date to see in date format

End Function
```

[image]